# JQuery scrollTo scrolls to the next DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

I have the following function:

```
function scrollToDiv(){
    var str = '.' + window.location.href.split('#').pop();
    $.scrollTo(str, {duration: 300});
}
```

It extracts the `test` from `www.example.com/#test` and sets `str` to `.test`. However, the scrollTo() scrolls to the div AFTER `<div class="test"></div>`. Why is that?

Update: I've noticed that the offset().top is showing wrong numbers for each div.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unnecessarily complex function. There is a property called `window.location.hash` which gets the exact part you want (even though that bit of your code works pretty well). A similar and more effective implementation of your code is:

```js
function scrollToAnchor(place){
    var cls = window.location.hash.replace("#", "."),
        sel = $(cls + ":eq(" + place + ")");
    place++;                
    $.scrollTo(sel, {duration: 300});
}
```

I have added a `place` argument that scrolls to the given place (indexed by 1 not 0 because I increment the variable to make it easier to understand). Notice I simply replace the hash symbol in the `hash` property value with a dot because that's what you need. I hope this has helped you a bit and let me know if you don't understand my changes. Here's a full HTML page using this function:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/master/jquery.scrollTo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #something {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 800px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="something">Test</a>
        <a class="something">Test</a>
        <a class="something">Test</a>
        <a class="something">Test</a>
        <a class="something">Test</a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function scrollToAnchor(place){
            var cls = window.location.hash.replace("#", "."),
                sel = $(cls + ":eq(" + place + ")");
            place++;                
            $.scrollTo(sel, {duration: 300});
        }
        scrollToAnchor(3);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Could've done a Fiddle or a CodePen project but you need to pass something as the hash (obviously) and that's a bit strange to try and mock up with editors like those. Just pass `#something` to that HTML file and it will do what you're seeking.

Comment: But I cannot use ids - I need to use classes. Also, my question remains the same - the scrollTo works with clases, but for some reason it scrolls to the NEXT div and not the one I specify.

Comment: I like the way you put it :)

Comment: @doitmyway: Can you show us the markup of the next div on your page?

Comment: I have 5 divs, which look the same. '<div class="classname"></div>'

Comment: It is still possible but let me work on a solution. Why must it be classes..?

Comment: This still doesn't work. I pass the id to the scrollTo() function, but the browser doesn't scroll to it.

Comment: I'm about to have it flawless. It does what you're looking for now and replaces the `#` with a `.`. Make sure to save this file.

Comment: Try it now! I think I finally understand your dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll to behaviour is normally executed on IDs by default by browsers. Hence, when you click on any link like http://example.com/#test , any decent browser will scroll to element which has id - test.
Try using ids instead of classes.

Comment: Browsers jump to <a> tags according to hashes, but it doesn't work with DIVs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346662/jquery-scrollto-scrolls-to-the-next-div/19346707?noredirect=1#show-editor-button - Try this, it is a link with ID of the `add another answer` button on this very page. Browser jumps do work with divs, and for that matter, any DOM element that can have an ID.

Comment: I have just added an ID to the div (id="test") and when I go to www.example.com/#test the browser doesn't scroll to the div.

Comment: Can we have a look at your page? Note that on Stackoverflow, you need to show us some code. So we can see the bigger picture and point you to anything you might be missing.